# Custom Tapatalk implementation and Android app

Tags: android, ios, forum

I've implemented a custom Tapatalk plugin for my forum (PHP). Everything works perfect on the iOS app, I can see the forums, the topics, log in, create topics, answer threads and so on.

The problem comes with the Android app, where I can only see the forums (the get_forum function). Everyting else results in an infinite loading screen.

In both cases I downloaded the latest version of the app from the App Store and Google Play respectively.

I have absolutely no clue on what is going wrong here. The XMLRPC sent and recieved are the same in both cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you should post the related code so we can see exactly what you are doing?